# Reference of any god being brahmin (by caste)

Tags: vedas, brahmins

Is there any reference(for ex. wears Janoi) in any Vedas or in any other book that describes **God as brahmin** (by **caste**)?

One reference I found in **Hanuman Chalisa** is,

> हाथ बज्र औ ध्वजा बिराजै ।
>
> काँधे मूँज जनेउ साजै ॥५॥

Comment: Yagnopavitam or Janeu/Janoi is worn by first 3 varnas, so wearing yagnopavitam is not the exact sign of being Bramhana.

Comment: In what sense of the world god or God are you asking? God (Brahman) is beyond all qualities and has no caste.

Comment: This distinction is usually seen in the 9 planets and the lesser gods (lesser than the trinity,and devi and other brahman-equivalent gods such as ganapati.)- Angaraka is a kshatriya, sani is a sudra. Agni is a brahmin. Brihaspati is a brahmin.  Indra is a kshatriya (this is inferred from the caste of suta maha muni who was born of the mixture of Indra's and Brihaspati's tejas). And so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All male Gods(Ganapaty,Shiva,Vishnu etc) wear the Yajnopavita.And we can't arrive at any conclusion regarding the caste(varna) of them just by looking at their Upavita.

For example,Ketu(one of the [Navagrahas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navagraha)) is regarded as an Antyaja(baseborn/outcaste) in the [Brihat Parashara Hora Shastra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brihat_Parashara_Hora_Shastra).But as per the [Ketu Pancha Vimsati Nama Stotram](http://stotrasamhita.net/wiki/Ketu_Panchavimshati_Nama_Stotram)(The Stotram comprised of the 25 names of Ketu),found in the Skanda Purana,even Ketu wears the sacred thread.

> raudrō rudrapriyō rudraḥ krūrakarmā sugandhadhṛk|
>   palāladhūmasaṅkāśaścitra**yajñōpavītadhṛk**||2||

[**Meaning**](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Sri_Kethu_Stotram)

> He who is angry, he who likes Shiva, he who is fierce, He who does
>   cruel deeds, He who is seen by pleasant smell, One who resembles the
>   smoke of husk, **one who is seen wearing sacred thread.**

So,the rules that apply to the human beings with respect to wearing the sacred thread(that is the Dvijas only should wear it) may not be valid for the Devas(divine beings) as well.