# Is Brahma/Prajapati/Hiranyagarbha said to be a Brahmin?

Tags: brahma, brahmins, trinity

[Is caste system only for humans?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21532/is-caste-system-only-for-humans)

has the caste of many RigVedic Gods - but Brahma/Prajapati/Hiranyagarbha is missing from the list.

Does any other scripture say that Brahma is a Brahmin and is that why Siva is said to have incurred a sin by cutting off his head?

Comment: Looks like duplicate .. see this answer - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21535

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is caste system only for humans?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21532/is-caste-system-only-for-humans)