# Is there some kind of varnashram system among the Devatas

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, puranas, varnashrama, devatas

Since the varnashram system is an important part of Sanatan Dharma and since Sanatan Dharma applies to the whole brahmanda (at least according to the Vedic people), I was wondering if some sort of system exist for the devatas. Such a system indeed seems to exist for beings other than humans. For instance, in the Bhisma Parva of the Mahabharata, Sanjaya told King Dhistrastra about the inhabitants of the various dwipas of bhu-mandala (note: I interpreted Jambhudvipa + lavan samudra as the earth and ocean we know and the bhu-mandala system as some sort of greater earth) and such inhabitants often had castes. Additionally, Sukracharya is a brahmin (since King Jajati initially refused to marry Sukracharya's daughter because she was a brahmin and he was a warrior) while the Daitya king Bhrishaparva was a warrior (because King Jajati married his daughter Sarmista via Gandarva vivah because they belonged to the same warrior caste) Now, among the devatas there is Deva-Guru Brihaspati who acts as the gods' guru and priest, Lord Indra performs various sacrifices such as Aswamedha and fights in wars like a kshatriya, and the devatas asked King Nahusa (who was a kshatriya) to take the title as Indra. **Does that mean Lord Brihaspati is a brahmin and Lord Indra and the other devatas are kshatriyas of the heavenly realms, or do they have have varnas? What scriptures (i.e. name and quotation/verse) mentions whether some sort of varnashram exists/does not exist for the gods?**

Comment: See this --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21532/4732